# Expanded tree cache full on marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am running the below query on the Query console of my MarkLogic application base on which I am retrieving the ids of those documents that matched by filter query. I face the Expanded tree cache full on execution.
My query :

```
let $a: = cts:search(doc(),
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("doc__doc_type"), cts:and-query(()))
)
for $doc in $a
return ($doc//base__unique_id/text())
```

How do I fine-tune this query?

The count of documents matching this query is 1336967. 
The configured tree size is 2048MB.

I need help in fine-tuning this query so that it returns values in pages.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options available to tune this query.

- Best Option: Assuming `base__unique_id` is in fact a unique ID you can put a range index on it and return all existing values from your query with [`cts:element-values`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values). This will be a much faster query and will also use much less memory as you won't be opening every document returned.
- Paginate your results. Don't return every result in one shot. Do it over the course of several queries. If you're just generating a list of all results you can also look at [CORB2](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) to help you do this in a scalable manner.
- If it makes sense to do so, you may want to look at assigning a namespace based on the document type to your data. This will yield smaller termlists (improved performance) and may simplify many of your query expressions.
- If you did not follow my first recommendation, you can try using an absolute XPath expression rather than the relative one you have now.
- If you did not follow my first recommendation, you can make your `cts:search` unfiltered. This will help with speed to results but likely not fix the expanded tree cache error.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't easily create an index and want to avoid blowing the expanded tree cache while ripping through all of the documents...

It may not be the fastest (and you may need to bump up your timeout limits), but you may be able to avoid **XDMP-EXPNTREECACHEFULL** errors by eliminating the FLWOR statements and using an expression that does not need to buffer any of the documents or values, such as:

```
cts:search(doc(),
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("doc__doc_type"), cts:and-query(()))
)//base__unique_id/text()
```

Comment: A range index would be rather expensive, since every value would be unique, so also no gain from cts:values returning distinct values. A range index would likely be faster though, since above does touch every doc in the search result set, potentially creating many read locks along the way as well.

Comment: Still a good answer though, since the fact that the search result is captured in a variable is the culprit of the cache error..

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate the result from `cts:search` by sub-sequencing the sequence returned by `cts:search` in the following way:

```
let $a := cts:search(doc(), cts:element-query(xs:QName("doc__doc_type"),cts:and-query(())) ) 
let $page1 := $a[1 to 10]
let $page2 := $a[11 to 20]
return $page1
```

**Background**

For more details see the [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered) on pagination and filtered searches.

The MarkLogic `cts:search` API by default performs the search in two steps:

1. Identify candidate fragment (document) IDs directly from indexes. This is done in memory and is fast. The results may contain false positives.
2. Candidate fragment IDs are loaded from disk and examined completely against all search criteria to filter out the false positives. This is done in memory and is slow.

If you would like to speed up the search and can tolerate false-positives you can skip the second step by performing an unfiltered search, resolving candidate fragments exclusively from indexes:

```
let $all-docs := cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query(()), "unfiltered")
return $all-docs[1 to 10]
```

Comment: You should actually be able to run this query unfiltered without any positives as he's checking if an element exists and not the position of where it exists. For more complex queries you can enable the position indexes to remove false positives. Making the search unfiltered will not help with the expanded tree cache however, as that is caused by loading each document into memory with his for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I understand correctly, the asker could speed up the search with an unfiltered search without any false positives? Of course they'd still need to subset the results to avoid pulling too many fragments into memory to address the expanded tree cache problem.

Comment: Correct. Whether you receive false positives or not depends on the query you are running and indexes available to resolve it. For the asker's query, there shouldn't be any false positives running it unfiltered.

Answer (score -1):

Use the "unfiltered" option. This will stop the search with the index resolution step not allowing to filter the documents. Filtering the documents means decompressing the document fragments one by one to search for the terms which will use the expanded tree cache. Given the number of results , it is best to go with this option.